# Script for merging and renaming shapekeys

Tags: scripting, shape-keys

I make avatars for vrchat but most of them have like 500+ shapekeys that I need to mix and rename by hand.
Is there a script out there that automatically does this for me?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Could you elaborate a bit and maybe give an example of what exactly is to be done?

Comment: Thank you!
What I need done involves mixing several shapekeys together.
normally that wouldnt be such a problem if there weren't 500 of them.
and I don't want to do it manually anymore.
So I was looking for a script that could recognize the names of shape keys and mix them automatically.